# What are the permissions required to edit page in a site in FrontPage 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2008, permissions

I'm in the process of upgrading an old web server from Windows 2003 with FrontPage Extensions to Windows 2008.

I have to allow FrontPage 2003 to connect to the resulting website. I don't have the option of moving away from FrontPage at this time.

When I open the site in Frontpage with a regular user account, it prompts me for credentials. When I provide an account with admin rights on the server, FrontPage allows me to perform exactly one action (open a folder, open a file, etc.) then prompts me for credentials again.

I didn't have this issue on the old server.

The "new" server is an upgrade-in-place so the permissions are the same.
If it makes a difference, we disabled FrontPage extensions before doing the OS upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

After much trial and error, it seems like the users need to be local administrators on the web server.

Obviously, this a scenario that forces us to implement many other safeguards.